Why is the set $A$ not closed under countable unions?
Let $A$ be the set of all finite unions of half open intervals of the form $(a,b], a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $(-\infty, b]$ or $(a,\infty), a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$.
I am reading that this set is an algebra, but not a $\sigma$-algebra, as it is closed under finite unions but not countable unions. Why is this?

You have $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} (-1, 1 - 1 / n] = (-1, 1)$ but $A$ does not contain any open intervals $(a, b)$ with $b < \infty$.
